# Insert a block of file in a xml

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to insert a block of file into XML using Ansible.

Ex.xml

```
<t1> ${t1}/k</t1>
<v1 c="k.tm"/>
```

I need to insert a block of code between (i.e after `<t1> ${t1}/k</t1>`) as per ex.xml

Can anyone help on this?

I tried using block in file but it ended up like this which is adding the block of code at the end of the XML.

```
- name: add a block
  blockinfile:
    path: ex.xml
    marker: "test"
  block:
    <k1></k1>
    <K2></k2>
  insertafter: "^<t1> ${t1}/k</t1>"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `insertafter` parameter is a regular expression so the '$' character won't match directly.  You'll need to escape it.

```
insertafter: "^<t1> \\${t1}/k</t1>"
```

A couple of other notes...

If you want your block to be inserted as you've written it with newlines, add a pipe right after `block`.  Otherwise your entire block will be written to the same line

```
block: |
    <k1></k1>
    <K2></k2>
```

The `marker` parameter should probably be an xml comment.  Also you should include the `{mark}` keyword so that Ansible knows to not insert the same block if it already exists in ex.xml.

```
marker: "<!-- {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->"
```